# No help collection was found

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, 2016

I did a fresh install of SharePoint 2016

When I click on the help button I see this error:

```
Unfortunately, help seems to be broken...

There aren't any help collections in the current language for the site you're using.
```

When I go to the site's help settings I see this:
[image]

I have run and re-run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard multiple time to no effect.

As per [this doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/939313) I tried using `Hcinstal.exe /act InstallAllHCs` but Hcinstal.exe doesn't seem to exist on sharepoint 2016

I also tried this, but it seemed to do nothing (completed without error though)

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Install-SPHelpCollection -All
```

EDIT:
Looks like I don't have any cabs? Can I manually extract them from somewhere? Like I said I ran the config wizard to no avail
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st you have to make sure the cab Files Exits.TO Check

- go to the following path `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\HCCab\1033\` and make sure you have the cab files in this folder. If you have different language Pack installed then you will check those folders as well( number folder).

After Making sure you have to run this Command.`Install-SPHelpCollection -All` Once the command completed successfully then you have to wait for couple of min before they installed. Then close the browser and reopen it and browse to the site collection.

Another Possible workaround is the install each file individually like this.

```
Install-SPHelpCollection -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files\Co
mmon Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\HCCab\1033\MS.OSS.HC.CAB"
```

Comment: All I have in this folder is one sad readme file

Comment: Looks like help files not installed

Comment: how do I manually install/get them?

Comment: I also found no HC.CAB in the install media for sql2016

Comment: How many servers u have? Check if it is on other servers?

Comment: Ah wait I do have cab files here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\HCCab\1033

Comment: Do you have 16 hive folder instead of 15?

Comment: Exactly that is path where for 2016 help files are

Comment: Ok help working now. I think it might have been my stupidity (not running Install-SPHelpCollection -All as admin or maybe it needed a second reboot)

Comment: Great, I am glad it is working. Please mark it answer if helpful along with vote